# Why multiply pixel aspect ratio to layer position value?

Tags: javascript, adobe, after-effects

I've been automating my After Effects project with expressions but got a question about my code

I purchased a preset but had to make adjustments with it, so I was digging up the expression from the project

This is the code for my null object scale property

---

> p1 = [thisComp.layer("Img 4: Mask 1 [1.0]").transform.position[0]*thisComp.pixelAspect, thisComp.layer("Img 4: Mask 1 [1.0]").transform.position[1]];

p2 = [thisComp.layer("Img 4: Mask 1 [1.3]").transform.position[0]*thisComp.pixelAspect, thisComp.layer("Img 4: Mask 1 [1.3]").transform.position[1]];

> 

l = length(p1,p2);

> 

[l,l];

---

this way, the null object is square with the other null object as the point.

However, I don't understand why I have to multiply "thisComp.pixelAspect", because I believe I already got the value for x with the code prior to the pixel aspect.

What is the point of multiplying pixel aspect ratio (in this project it was Square Pixels).

Thank you!

I tried to take the *thisComp.pixelAspect from the expression, but if I do so, it doesn't change anything